# Problem installing codai_sick_s300 (missing resource)

Tags: serial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now that I found the appropriate driver, which would be the codai_sick_s300 I encountered a new problem. This package apparently depends on a very specific other package called serial_port. My issue with all that is that for some reason the ROS pages of the codai version for the Standard and Advanced versions of the S300 are gone and the appropriate package is gone as well, can't get to it with the Waybackmachine either.

Can anyone tell me how to use this driver nevertheless, or where I can change this dependency to use a different serial driver?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64037/problem-installing-codai_sick_s300-(missing-resource)/) by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like I was a little fast to ask on this one, right before I was about to call one of our contacts I came up with a better google search word and found the driver I was searching for, even more I got everything to run after a little tempering, I now get the raw data I was searching for.

Here's what I did to get there:

1. Found the driver serial_port which the codai_sick_s300 was programmed to use: searched for: svn code "serial_port"
2. The codai driver used one deprecated method and a false name.

stacks/codai_sick_s300/ros/src/codai_sick_s300_standard.cpp => codai_sick_s300.cpp

Then in the same file:

set_intensities_size(num_readings); => intensities.resize(num_readings);
set_ranges_size(num_readings); => ranges.resize(num_readings);

After that everything was able to compile just fine, made a launch file for it, attached and started the scanner, and got the data.

---

Originally posted by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) with karma: 73 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KrishKannan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/41611/krishkannan_007/) on 2019-05-20**:
can u give the link of the package that u used?